# How to close popup after checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, checkbox, popup

I have a specific request from a customer. I'm more a designer than a developer. I'm working on a WordPress theme with a custom contact form integrated.

I need to place a link on the "**Submit**" button that when clicked will open a confirm popup. In the popup, the user would find a checkbox with a text saying "*I declare that I have read, understood and accepted the information on the processing of my personal data*".

Once they check the checkbox, a "**Continue**" button on the bottom of that popup should enable (prior to checking the checkbox, the Continue button is disabled). When the Continue button is clicked, the popup would go away and the form will be launched.

Here's how I would like the popup to look like:

[image: Popup preview png]

Here's the HTML of the form:

```
<form method="post" name="contactform" class="peThemeContactForm">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 animated hiding" data-animation="slideInLeft">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Full Name",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Email",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Phone",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 animated hiding" data-animation="slideInRight">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Message",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>" required ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-custom up animated hiding" value="<?php _e("Send Message",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>" data-animation="fadeInUpBig">
</form>
```

Comment: what's plugins do you use?

Comment: I think your title is wrong. You don't want the dialogue box to close when the checkbox is ticked - you want the Continue/Confirm button to be re-enabled, and it is that control that closes the dialogue.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @RobertWade: good edits. I'd add that if you see chatty/begging material ("please help me", "this is urgent", etc) you can zap it rather than spending time cleaning it up. We don't want it anyway `:-)`

Comment: @halfer good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it with JavaScript jQuery. So install the jQuery plugin first.
Put the popup inside the form like this and change the submit button to a onclick event:

```
    <form method="post" name="contactform" class="peThemeContactForm">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 animated hiding" data-animation="slideInLeft">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Full Name",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Email",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Phone",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 animated hiding" data-animation="slideInRight">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php _e("Message",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?>" required ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a onclick="popupshow()" class="btn btn-custom up animated hiding" data-animation="fadeInUpBig"><?php echo _e("Send Message",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'); ?></a> //Submit-Button

//PopUP
<div id="popup" style="display:none;">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="checkboxclick()">
<button type="submit" id="mycheckbox" disabled>Continue</button>
</div>

</form>
```

Now do the Javascript Functions (Put them in your head section):

```
    <script>

        function popupshow() {
            document.getElementById("popup").style = "";
            }

        function checkboxclick() {
        if (document.getElementById("mycheckbox").checked) {
            $('#mycheckbox').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
            $('#mycheckbox').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }

        </script>
```

This should show the popup if you click the submit-button and should activate the continue-button if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You are use [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals). If the control that should close the dialog is placed within the modal, then just add `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute to this control. To lock or unlock **Continue** button use handler for the chechkbox click event.

Also you could implement another sequence of user actions that is demonstrated below.

```js
$(".modal").on('show.bs.modal', lock);
$("#MyModal [type=checkbox]").click(lock);
$("#MyModal .btn-primary").click(function() {
  $("#MyForm").submit();
});

function lock() {
  var flag = $("#MyModal [type=checkbox]").prop('checked');
  if (!flag) {
    $("#MyModal .btn-primary").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
    $("#MyModal .btn-primary").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Privacy Policy</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> I declare that I have read, understood and accepted the information on the processing of my personal data.
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Form with confirmation request -->
<form id="MyForm" action="/">
  <p>You will have to accept our privacy policy to submit the form data.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The **Submit** button opens dialog box that contains the checkbox for confirmation. The **Continue** button submits the form, but it is disabled until the checkbox will be checked.